# Schedule - User defined text that can reference array elements

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the process of writting a macro for collecting debris. At each location, a series of tasks will be performed to recover the debris. The majority of these locations will require the same activities so im assuming they are all the same and the user can modify them as required after the macro is complete. Below is the current code:

```
Public Function additional_Lines(ByVal target_ID)

ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
Dim offset As String

offset = "     "

Dim additional_Text As Variant
additional_Text = Array(offset & "Relocate to " & target_ID, offset & "Recover " & target_ID, offset & "Recover basket")

For i = 0 To UBound(additional_Text)
    ActiveCell.Value = additional_Text(i)
    ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

End Function
```

This generates the following output

```
OSP-040
     Relocate to OSP-040
     Recover OSP-040
     Recover basket
ZDUN-THI-004
     Relocate to ZDUN-THI-004
     Recover ZDUN-THI-004
     Recover basket
OSP-046
     Relocate to OSP-046
     Recover OSP-046
     Recover basket
OSP-056
     Relocate to OSP-056
```

Where OSP-056, OSP-046, ZDUN-THI-004, OSP-004 are the debris locations.

I'm wanting to allow the user to type in the text they would like to insert between the debris locations in one of the sheets ie:

```
 Relocate to (Debris ID Number)
 Recover (Debris ID Number)
```

Where Debris ID Number is stored in an array. Is it possible to read the 2 string above and then replace the (Debris ID Number) with a variable so i can update it from the array of debris IDs?

Comment: This is a bit vague. Re 1 could use an message box Y/N?, re 2 you need to concatenate.

Comment: @SJR hopefully thats a little clearer? Essentially i dont know the strings they are going to input, but am assuming they will reference the debris target somewhere in them. So i need a placemarker in their strings which i can then replace with the current debris ID.

Comment: Do you have a look up table? Can't you restrict what they enter to specifically what you need using data validation or a dropdown box?

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace function which can search a string for a specified string, and once it finds it, can replace it. Rather than replace it with a static string, i have referenced an array of the debris IDs.

```
For y = 1 To UBound(additional_Lines)
    new_additional_Lines(y) = Replace(additional_Lines(y, 1), ID, " " & target_ID & " ")
Next y
```

Thanks again for everyones help.